# Chart.js 2 line charts with separate dataset labels

Tags: chart.js

I need build 2 lines charts with different sets of labels

here is example https://jsfiddle.net/o5dtzwn1/

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {      
  datasets: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],       
    labels: [
      'green',
      'yellow',
      'red',
      'purple',
      'blue',
    ]
  }, {
    data: [6, 7, 8],
    labels: [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ],
  }, ]
},
options: {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
}
```

});

How can I do this?

Comment: Here is solution. Need combine labels of all values- ['green', 'yellow', 'red', 'purple', 'blue', 'a', 'b', 'c']. Then data need use such format: {x:"green", y:1} or  {x:"a", y:10}

Comment: Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/zbkwps2m/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that could help you, Now I have made different line chart with four different data with different counts.
Here i have made three label array and attached to tick callback function randomly.
You can choose whichever apropriate, but make sure bigger atrray lenth should come
in to data: { labels: label1}.
       Check link [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/hiren65/0jfothmq/7/)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var label1 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg"];
var label2 = ["1900", "1950", "1999", "2050"];
var label3 = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"];

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: label1,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Europe",
      type: "line",
      borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
      data: [408, 547, 675, 934],
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: "Africa",
      type: "line",
      borderColor: "magenta",
      data: [133, 221, 783, 2478, 1900, 1200],
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: "Europe",
      type: "line",
      borderColor: "green",
      data: [408, 547, 675, 734, 200],
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: "Africa",
      type: "line",
      borderColor: "red",
      //backgroundColorHover: "#3e95cd",
      data: [133, 221, 783, 2478],
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Population growth (millions): Europe & Africa'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            if (label3[index] === undefined) {
              label3[index] = "no data ";
            }
            if (label2[index] === undefined) {
              label2[index] = "no data ";
            }
            return "l3 " + label3[index] + "l2 " + label2[index] + ' $' + value;
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is possible to use separate dots for labels on xAxis?

Comment: yes i think you want each labels for all data sets looks in multiline warped i.e. separete lines. i made combined all label with function combineAllLabel(a1,a2,a3){..} and created new label Array that array assigned to  data: {
        labels: combineAllLabel(label1,label2,label3),...} . check link here https://jsfiddle.net/hiren65/dsv6quyc/2/

Comment: thx for help, I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712449/chart-js-2-line-charts-with-separate-dataset-labels/#comment100004402_56712449

Answer (score 0):

```js
//use following code that might helpful
 var ctx = $("#myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [168,170,178,190,203,276,408,547,675,734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10,16,24,38,74,167,508,784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2,2,7,26,82,172,312,433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is necessary that you mention the changes you did in your code and why you did it. That way the OP can learn about it and future visitors can too.

Comment: This code show same labels for each chart, my charts has different data and labels, even different data count

Answer (score 0):

I think this one as you mention have different label and differnt data and count

```js
// here is link https://codepen.io/hiren65/pen/ydMZaJ 
var ctx = $("#myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {      
      datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 6, 11, 5], 
        type: "line",
        borderColor: "red",
        labels: [
          'green',
          'yellow',
          'red',
          'purple',
          'blue',
        ]
      }, {
        data: [6, 7, 8],
        type: "line",
        borderColor: "#123ea2",
        labels: [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c'
        ],
      },  {
        data: [6, 3, 8,10,11,4],
        type: "line",
        borderColor: "#6cc",
        labels: [
          'a1',
          'b1',
          'c1',
          'e1'
        ],
      },]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is the same code as my in first message, it not works as expected, it not show labels at bottom, also not show full line charts